# how to load a .vim file on a mode line

Tags: vim, modeline

For a few specific files I need a set of mappings, which I don't want to be active in my `~/.vimrc` file. So I defined them in a file `XXX.vim`.
How can I load `XXX.vim` on a mode line and where should it be placed in my `.vim` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can't source a script in a modeline for obvious reason. All you can do is set *some* options.

The canonical way to have some options/mappings/commands available for some files and not others is to use an `:help autocommand` like this one:

```
augroup mystuff
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.foo nnoremap <buffer> <key> bar
augroup END
```

You can use the pattern above for all files with the `foo` extension or something like `foo/bar/*` for all file under `foo/bar/`, etc.

If you want those mappings only for a specific *filetype*, say `ruby`, then it is best to use the built-in ftplugin mechanism:

1. Make sure you have **either** of the following lines in your `vimrc`:

   ```
   filetype plugin on
   filetype plugin indent on
   filetype indent plugin on
   ```
2. Create this file (and the necessary directories) if it doesn't exist:

   ```
   " Unix-like system
   ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim

   " Windows
   %userprofile%\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\ruby.vim
   ```
3. Add your buffer-local mappings to that file:

   ```
   nnoremap <buffer> <key> something
   ```

Comment: My problem is that I want the mappings for /some/ of my .tex files, not for all. The above does not seem to be a solution for that. But I'll have to study the details...

Comment: Well you will have to find a way to discriminate those files. What is described above is the general mechanism, it's up to you, now, to adapt it to your own circumstances.